# How to Import a Text File to a List in HTML5 / JavaScript even if it is not JSON or CSV?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new here, please be kind.  I am trying to import a text file into a HTML nested list.  The HTML output I am trying to achieve would look like this:

```html
    <ul>
        <li>FAVORITE SITES
            <ul>
                <li>eBay</li>
                <li>Google</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>AVOIDED SITES
            <ul>
                <li>Yahoo</li>
                <li>CraigsList</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>OTHER SITES
            <ul>
                <li>Alexa</li>
                <li>Amazon</li>
                <li>Jet</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

The text file I am loading using `<input type="file">` is not formatted in a usual way - it is not JSON or CSV, it is formatted like below:

```
FAVORITE SITES {
!Variable=eBay
!Variable=Google
}

AVOIDED SITES {
!Variable=Yahoo
!Variable=CraigsList
}

OTHER SITES {
!Variable=Alexa
!Variable=Amazon
!Variable=Jet
}
```

Is there any way to load parse and input the values of the text file and load them into the list even though the file is in this non-standard format or will I need to change the format of the text file?  Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Define 2 sound regexes and parse the content by repeatedly calling its exec() method will be a practical solution.

Comment: Forgive me, I am a novice but thank you so much for the comment.  Is there a regex to be had because the !Variable= is always the same but the headings, example "FAVORITE SITES" are always different.  There may be many of them and they will not be known before it could be "FAVORITE SITES {   }" or "CHICKEN DINNER {   }", etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let s = `FAVORITE SITES {
!Variable=eBay
!Variable=Google
}

AVOIDED SITES {
!Variable=Yahoo
!Variable=CraigsList
}

OTHER SITES {
!Variable=Alexa
!Variable=Amazon
!Variable=Jet
}`;

var ul = document.createElement('ul');

ul.innerHTML = s.replace(/(\})/gim, "</ul>\n</li>")
         .replace(/\{/gim, "\n<ul>")
         .replace(/!Variable=(\w+)\s*\n/gim, "<li>$1</li>\n")
         .split(/\s*\n\s*\n/)
         .map(v => v = '\n<li>' + v)
         .join('');

document.body.appendChild(ul);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please reference this code snippet;

```
// assign the file content to s
let s = `FAVORITE SITES {
!Variable=eBay
!Variable=Google
}

AVOIDED SITES {
!Variable=Yahoo
!Variable=CraigsList
}

OTHER SITES {
!Variable=Alexa
!Variable=Amazon
!Variable=Jet
}`;

let a = s.replace(/[\n\r]/g, '').split(/(.+?) \{(.+?)\}/g);

for (let i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i += 3) {
    // a[i + 1] is the outer li text
    let a2 = a[i + 2].split(/!Variable=([^!]+)/g);
    // every 2nd item of a2 is the inner li text
    // or you can filter out '' items
    // you can apply the same trick to a as well, but need to modify for-loop accordingly
    let a3 = a2.filter(v => v !== '');
    // now all items are a3 can be used directly as inner li text
}
```